# Facebook og:image URL must be valid forever?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Let's start with a very short definition: The URL given by `og:image` should point to a JPG, minimum 200x200 pixels, which Facebook will then use as thumbnail of the posted "article".

My question is: is it true that the URL has to be valid only at the time where Facebook is fetching the JPG?

If the above is true, one could conclude:
- Facebook fetches the JPG referenced by `og:image` and stores it locally at the FB infrastructure.
- The post at Facebook continues to show the thumbnail even if the initial URL provided by `og:image` does not work at a future moment?

Comment: Facebook will cache it. If you want it to be available forever it needs to be available when Facebook rescrapes the URL

Comment: Many thanks @Wizkid , do you know the conditions for rescraping?

Comment: Every few weeks I believe.

Comment: Any idea what happens if the URL is not valid anymore? Does the cached thumbnail disappear?

Comment: No idea. Does it matter?

Comment: Just to clarify: let's assume you post URL1 to Facebook and the thumbnail URL for it is URL2. By "rescraping" I understand that Facebook will call URL1 again and will get an updated thumbnail URL which might be identical to URL2 or a new one. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Facebook will rescrape the URL and use what ever image is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: YES, the URL to the thumbnail (referenced by `og:image`) must be valid at the time where the post happens. The JPG is cached at Facebook.
However, Facebook will rescrape the initially posted URL of the article and will read again the (new) thumbnail-URL. When that happens, the new thumbnail-URL must be valid. The old URL is not important anymore.